# External ResourceDictionary in several projects

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to include my resource dictionary (xamarin) in several android applications because every app should have the same background, labels .. you know what I mean. :D

**What have I tried?**

- I've had tested if my style and the application work together in the same project.
  I've created a external .net standardlibrary to centralize it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ResourceDictionary
       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

        <Color x:Key="PrimaryText">#FAFAFA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SecondaryText">#F5F5F5</Color>
        <Color x:Key="HintText">#80FFFFFF</Color>
```

- I've add the reference (Styles.dll) to my application
- When I want to add my style to (e.g.) my labels I use "StaticResource" and "DynamicResource". When I use StaticResource and run the program it throws "*Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 40:20. StaticResource not found for key ErrorTextColor*'". 
  When I use DynamicResource the application starts but it doesn't take the style.
- In app.xaml I've add the namespace and assembly

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Styles;assembly=Styles"
                 xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.DryIoc;assembly=Prism.DryIoc.Forms"

        <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                  <theme:BlackStyleDictionary/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Application.Resources>
    </prism:PrismApplication>
```

- After I googled a lot I found out that I actually can use "mergedDictionary" to include it to my project but that doesn't work - also "ResourceDictionary Source="...Path" doesn't work for me.

```
    <Application.Resources>        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
              <theme:BlackStyleDictionary/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

- I spent much time to google but don't find an answer so I need you to resolve it. :)

**What works?**

As I mentioned above when I had my style.xaml in my current app everything works fine, so there is no problem with the resourcedirectionary.

---

If you need more information for the solution feel free to ask for it. :)

Many thanks in advance,

JaqSparrow

Comment: So basically you have a standalone assembly that has all your `StaticResources`?

Comment: Yes, its in my library.

Comment: Have you declared these static resources in your current library somewhere? They will only be available if you add them to your current assemblies Application class

Comment: Maybe I've misleading above when I say "reference". Yes, I'd add it to my current assemblies in my application class. There is the styles.dll.

Comment: I would like to see your full App.Xaml if you do not mind

Comment: I edit it for you. Thats my app.xaml.

Comment: Can you try this out `<Application.Resources><theme:BlackStyleDictionary/>
</Application.Resources>`

Comment: Doesn't work. Same issue. :/

Comment: I have a feeling there could be something wrong with your ResourceDictionary in general... Can i take a look at that

Comment: Also, confirm your build action for that class...

Comment: Thanks for you help. The first code snippet I wrote is my ResourceDictionary. After that there's just "<Style TargetType.... <Setter Property....>" Nothing else. I tried to build it as a pag and as a embedded ressource and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should try content or resource once and check

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Maybe you expect that I know all the basics but I'm in an apprenticeship for 3 months now and maybe I don't see everything thats totally clear for you.

Comment: Check the build action in properties and you will understand what I am talking about

Comment: I changed the build action from my ResourceDictionary in content and tried it and in resource and tried it. Neither works. I thinks there is a small issue and I can't find it..

Comment: Could there be an issue because of Prism?

Comment: I do not think so, prism isn't the issue

Comment: Thanks for your help since friday. I'd forget to implement "InitializeComponent();" in the xaml.cs-file.

Comment: Oh okay so is it working now? if yes let me know so I can add it as an answer so others can find it...

Comment: Yes, now its working great and have no issues anymore. If you want it, you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the InitializeComponent method was not called in the ResourceDictionaries which was in turn never loading these into the Resources Dictionary and causing issues.

Adding `InitializeComponent` to the constructor solved the issue.

Eg:

```
public MyResources()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```